# java How to read 2 different datatypes in one line using a Scanner

Tags: java

i need to use a Scanner where the first word is a string an the second a double for e.x.
"Drive 5" but both need to be written onto the same line in the scanner

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   String befehl = scanner.nextLine(); double wert = scanner.nextDouble();`

Comment: After pressing the enter you can't read the same line anymore. You can read the whole line as a string then split via space (it depends on you). It will give you a string array. You can convert array's first element to double.

ex: Double.valueOf(array[1])

Comment: Use a second `Scanner` to parse the `String` returned by the first `Scanner`s `nextLine` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Scanner#next` and then `Scanner#nextDouble`.

```
String befehl = scanner.next();
double wert = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I think people miss the point and power of `Scanner`.

Use your first `Scanner` to read the next line of input from the user, then use another `Scanner` to perform the parsing/validation of that input, independently.

This has the added benefit of ensuring that the input `Scanner` is kept clean and up-to-date (and avoids all those "my scanner is skipping input" questions ) and isolates the responsibility for parsing the input.

For example...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.nextLine();
Scanner parser = new Scanner(text);

if (parser.hasNext()) {
    String leadingText = parser.next();
    if (parser.hasNextDouble()) {
        double value = parser.nextDouble();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input, expecting a double value");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Inavlid input, expecting text");
}
```